# How to remove the Large White space at the bottom of my webpage?

Tags: css, html

I have this problem of having a huge white space at the bottom of my web page. I tried for many hours to fix the problem but I can't seem to find where I have gone wrong. Can anybody please help me with the problem? I have attached my code samples below...
Here's my code sample. (HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web Page Exercise 2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="UpperHeader"></div>



        <div class="SliitLogo">
            <img src="images/SLIIT Logo.png" width="25%" height="75">
        </div>

        <div class="Login">
            <a href="#">Login</a>
        </div>

        <div class="Register">
            <a href="#">Register</a>
        </div>

        <div class="SliitLibrary">
            <h1>SLIIT<span id="Space">LIBRARY</span></h1>
        </div>

        <div id="UpperNavigationBar">
            <div class="UpperNavigationBarContents">
                <ul> 
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 100px;color: white;">Home</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 120px;color: white;">About Us</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 145px;color: white">Membership</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 100px;color: white">Search</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 150px;color: white">New Arrivals</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 145px;color: white">Staff</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="BackgroundPicture"></div>

        <h3 style="position: relative;top: -610px; left: 10px;">Categories</h3>
        <div class="SideNavagationBar1">
            <UL TYPE="none">
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">OPAC Search</a></LI> 
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">New Arrivals</a></LI> 
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">How to Become a Member</a></LI>
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Central Bank of Sri Lanka</a></LI>    
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">e-Repository</a></LI>    
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Dictionary</a></LI> 
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Library Policies</a></LI>
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">University of Moratuwa</a></LI>    
            </UL>
        </div>

        <h3 style="position: relative;top: -590px;left: 10px;">E-Resources</h3>
        <div class="SideNavagationBar2">
            <UL TYPE="none">
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;color: black;">Find the Journals</div></LI> 
                <LI><a style="text-decoration: none;">Online Journals</a></LI> 
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;">Access the available databases</div></LI>
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Databases</a></LI>    
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;">Getting start with Research?</div></LI>    
                <LI><a href="#"style="text-decoration: none;">Research Papers</a></LI> 
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;">What is done already?</div></LI>
                <LI><a href="#"style="text-decoration: none;">Thesis Dissertion</a></LI>   
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;">Help!!!</div></LI>
                <LI><a href="#"style="text-decoration: none;">Library Guide</a></LI>
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;">Turnitin</div></LI>
                <LI><a href="#"style="text-decoration: none;">Turnitin</a></LI>
            </UL>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my `CSS` sample for the above `HTML`

```
    .UpperHeader{
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;

}
.SliitLogo{
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;

}
.Login{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    right: 100px;
    top: 40px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.Register{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 40px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.SliitLibrary{
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    right: 20px;
    top: -200px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Lifetime;
}
#Space{
    display:inline-block; 
    margin-left: 10px;

}
#UpperNavigationBar{
    background-color: #333333;
    position: relative;
    top: -140px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 98%;
    height: 35px;

}
.UpperNavigationBarContents li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top: -7px;
    left: -20px;
    color: white; 
}
.SideNavagationBar1{
    position: relative;
    top: -600px;
    font-size: 14px;   


}

.SideNavagationBar1 li>a{
    color: blue;   

}
.SideNavagationBar1 li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 3px;

}
.SideNavagationBar2{
    position: relative;   
    margin-left: 0;
    top: -600px;
    font-size: 14px;   
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.SideNavagationBar2 li>a{
    color: blue;   
}
.SideNavagationBar2 li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.BackgroundPicture{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    top: -130px;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 80vh;   
}
```

**The problem is I see a huge white space below the the web page. A huge one. Can anybody please help me???**

```css
.UpperHeader{
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    
}
.SliitLogo{
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    
}
.Login{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    right: 100px;
    top: 40px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.Register{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 40px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.SliitLibrary{
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    right: 20px;
    top: -200px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Lifetime;
}
#Space{
    display:inline-block; 
    margin-left: 10px;
    
}
#UpperNavigationBar{
    background-color: #333333;
    position: relative;
    top: -140px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 98%;
    height: 35px;
    
}
.UpperNavigationBarContents li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top: -7px;
    left: -20px;
    color: white; 
}
.SideNavagationBar1{
    position: relative;
    top: -600px;
    font-size: 14px;   
    
    
}

.SideNavagationBar1 li>a{
    color: blue;   
    
}
.SideNavagationBar1 li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    
}
.SideNavagationBar2{
    position: relative;   
    margin-left: 0;
    top: -600px;
    font-size: 14px;   
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.SideNavagationBar2 li>a{
    color: blue;   
}
.SideNavagationBar2 li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.BackgroundPicture{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    top: -130px;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 80vh;   
}
```

```html
<!-- IT No: IT17157124 -->
<!-- ID No: 952314017V -->
<!-- Name: Jananth Banuka Jayarathna -->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web Page Exercise 2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="UpperHeader"></div>
        
        
    
        <div class="SliitLogo">
            <img src="images/SLIIT Logo.png" width="25%" height="75">
        </div>

        <div class="Login">
            <a href="#">Login</a>
        </div>

        <div class="Register">
            <a href="#">Register</a>
        </div>

        <div class="SliitLibrary">
            <h1>SLIIT<span id="Space">LIBRARY</span></h1>
        </div>

        <div id="UpperNavigationBar">
            <div class="UpperNavigationBarContents">
                <ul> 
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 100px;color: white;">Home</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 120px;color: white;">About Us</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 145px;color: white">Membership</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 100px;color: white">Search</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 150px;color: white">New Arrivals</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><p style="width: 145px;color: white">Staff</p></a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="BackgroundPicture"></div>
        
        <h3 style="position: relative;top: -610px; left: 10px;">Categories</h3>
        <div class="SideNavagationBar1">
            <UL TYPE="none">
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">OPAC Search</a></LI> 
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">New Arrivals</a></LI> 
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">How to Become a Member</a></LI>
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Central Bank of Sri Lanka</a></LI>    
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">e-Repository</a></LI>    
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Dictionary</a></LI> 
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Library Policies</a></LI>
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">University of Moratuwa</a></LI>    
            </UL>
        </div>
        
        <h3 style="position: relative;top: -590px;left: 10px;">E-Resources</h3>
        <div class="SideNavagationBar2">
            <UL TYPE="none">
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;color: black;">Find the Journals</div></LI> 
                <LI><a style="text-decoration: none;">Online Journals</a></LI> 
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;">Access the available databases</div></LI>
                <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Databases</a></LI>    
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;">Getting start with Research?</div></LI>    
                <LI><a href="#"style="text-decoration: none;">Research Papers</a></LI> 
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;">What is done already?</div></LI>
                <LI><a href="#"style="text-decoration: none;">Thesis Dissertion</a></LI>   
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;">Help!!!</div></LI>
                <LI><a href="#"style="text-decoration: none;">Library Guide</a></LI>
                <LI><div style="text-decoration: none;">Turnitin</div></LI>
                <LI><a href="#"style="text-decoration: none;">Turnitin</a></LI>
            </UL>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should

- avoid relative positioning if you really don't need it. Because relatively positioned elements occupy the same space as if they would be statically positioned (by default).
- place elements in needed containers.

Demo:

```css
body {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  margin: 0;
}

.UpperHeader {
  background-color: #808080;
  height: 160px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.SliitLogo {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.Login {
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.Register {
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.SliitLibrary {
  color: white;
  font-family: Lifetime;
}

#Space {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#UpperNavigationBar {
  background-color: #333333;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 98%;
  height: 35px;
}

.UpperNavigationBarContents li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

.SideNavagationBar1 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.SideNavagationBar1 li>a {
  color: blue;
}

.SideNavagationBar1 li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.SideNavagationBar2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.SideNavagationBar2 li>a {
  color: blue;
}

.SideNavagationBar2 li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="UpperHeader">
  <div class="SliitLogo">
    <img src="images/SLIIT Logo.png" width="25%" height="75">
  </div>

  <div class="Login">
    <a href="#">Login</a>
  </div>

  <div class="Register">
    <a href="#">Register</a>
  </div>

  <div class="SliitLibrary">
    <h1>SLIIT<span id="Space">LIBRARY</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="UpperNavigationBar">
  <div class="UpperNavigationBarContents">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
            <p style="width: 100px;color: white;">Home</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
            <p style="width: 120px;color: white;">About Us</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
            <p style="width: 145px;color: white">Membership</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
            <p style="width: 100px;color: white">Search</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
            <p style="width: 150px;color: white">New Arrivals</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
            <p style="width: 145px;color: white">Staff</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Categories</h3>
<div class="SideNavagationBar1">
  <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">OPAC Search</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">New Arrivals</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">How to Become a Member</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Central Bank of Sri Lanka</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">e-Repository</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Dictionary</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Library Policies</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">University of Moratuwa</a></div>

<h3>E-Resources</h3>
<div class="SideNavagationBar2">
  <UL TYPE="none">
    <LI>
      <div style="text-decoration: none;color: black;">Find the Journals</div>
    </LI>
    <LI><a style="text-decoration: none;">Online Journals</a></LI>
    <LI>
      <div style="text-decoration: none;">Access the available databases</div>
    </LI>
    <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Databases</a></LI>
    <LI>
      <div style="text-decoration: none;">Getting start with Research?</div>
    </LI>
    <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Research Papers</a></LI>
    <LI>
      <div style="text-decoration: none;">What is done already?</div>
    </LI>
    <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Thesis Dissertion</a></LI>
    <LI>
      <div style="text-decoration: none;">Help!!!</div>
    </LI>
    <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Library Guide</a></LI>
    <LI>
      <div style="text-decoration: none;">Turnitin</div>
    </LI>
    <LI><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Turnitin</a></LI>
  </UL>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps, but when you use some relative positioning, keep in mind that the original place of the DOM element keeps.
In your CSS you have many element that have relative position with negative values, so, white space is the "ghost" of the orignal places of these elements.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But how can I use the positioning?

Comment: As Vadim said, you don't have in your case to use relative positionning, just use normal position that follow the HTML flow and it would do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much